# Debezium message compatible with format that kafka-connect sink connectors expect

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I have a `debezium` instance which tracks the changes on `postgres` and sends the change messages to `kafka`. At the other side of `kafka` I have `kafka connect` with `amazon redshift sink connector` and the message format that connector expects is not compatible with message format that `debezium` sends to `kafka`. Is there any way to force debezium to send a message that `amazon redshift sink connector` can accept ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using [New Record State Extraction SMT](https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/transformations/event-flattening.html) either at `source` or `sink` connector side.